# Where is Firefox's plugins directory?

Tags: firefox

I know that there are [extensive, "proper" methods for installing Firefox plugins](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FirefoxPlugins). However, I would like to know where the folder is for linking shared-object (`.so`) files, such as `libnpjp2.so` and `libflashplayer.so` so that I can install plugins the "old-fashioned" way. In Firefox 21, I would have put it in `~/.mozilla/firefox/*[profile name].default/browser/plugins` but that folder is no longer there. It keeps jumping around as Firefox changes. In `about:plugins` I still see all the plugins that I would have put there.

Can anyone tell me where the folder is? I already checked the folders in `/usr/lib/firefox` and `/usr/lib/mozilla`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> Please read the update at the end of this answer regarding changes in Firefox 52.

Acording to the Firefox developer [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference/Plug-in_Basics#How_Gecko_Finds_Plug-ins) plugins live here:

- Directory pointed to by `MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH` environment variable
- `~/.mozilla/plugins`
- `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins` (on **non-Ubuntu** 64-bit systems, `/usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins` might be used instead)
- [Plug-ins within toolkit bundles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Shipping_a_plugin_as_a_Toolkit_bundle)
- `[Profile directory]/plugins`, where `[Profile directory]` is a user profile directory

#### Update for Firefox >=52

As of Firefox 52 support for NPAPI plugins has been dropped. All plugins living in one of the above directories are ignored, with the exception of Adobe Flash.

If you installed Flash with the *flashplugin-installer* package, it's loaded through a symlink in `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins` that ultimately links to `/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so`.

Comment: Mine is 64-bit system but i found out that it is at `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins`. Also it is a good idea to have a look at `about:plugins` tab that may give a hint.

Comment: Fredrick Gauss's comment holds good for 14.04 too.

Comment: @learner, thanks. The info is directly from the Firefox documentation. Ubuntu puts 64bit libs in /usr/lib and 32bit libs in /usr/lib32 instead of having a lib64 directory. So I changed the answer a little to reflect that.

Comment: @FredrickGauss Great suggestion `about:plugins`. This way I can instantly get exact plugin directory path and verify the update afterwards by just refreshing and seeing the 'state: UPDATE_AVAILABLE_<SOMETEXT> ' is gone. So Helpful.

Comment: As of Firefox 50 on Ubuntu 16.04.1, none of these directories is where the plugins are. `about:plugins` shows that Flash comes from /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer, but I couldn't find anything symlinking to that path. [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/583260/oracle-java-plugin-not-recognized-by-firefox-35-0-1) suggests deleting `pluginreg.dat`.

Comment: @DanDascalescu actually nothing changed. I'm on Firefox 53 with Ubuntu 16.10 and Ubuntu 17.04. For me plugins live in `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins`. There's a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/mozilla-flashplugin` which is itself a symlink to `/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so`. I'll update my answer reflecting a few other changes, though.

Answer (score 12):

I am on KDE 32bit 14.04 version. Firefox is already installed.

user Richard got negative reputation by telling us the correct path:

```
/usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins
```

If you are proper linux user, it's no problem to move libflashplayer.so file to this directory as root user!

Youtube works after dat!

Comment: Can confirm Firefox >60 on Ubuntu-based >18.04 64-bits will also work with this.

Answer (score 4):

Users should place plugins in `/usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins` as root.

Comment: Users should do nothing as root.

Comment: This is only in the case you want a certain plugin to be automatically installed in all new user profiles. As a single user, you shouldn't install anything at all in this directory.

Comment: @darent Where should we install the plugin then?

Comment: @iamcreasy see the answer by user mnies

Answer (score 1):

I found there is a directory `/usr/lib/firefox/brower/plugins/`.

My Ubuntu version is 16.04 LTS. [How to enable flash player in Mozilla Firefox in Ubuntu](http://www.debugpoint.com/2015/06/how-to-enable-flash-player-in-mozilla-firefox-in-ubuntu/) is a helpful article. If there is not a directory named `lib64`, just copy the correct file to `/usr/lib/firefox/browser/plugins/`. Based on my experience, it also works well.

Answer (score 0):

As a new Ubuntu user, I've been suggested to use the path mentioned by the `about:plugins` firefox command. In my case, it's pointing to `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/`.

Just mentioning here as I haven't seen this being mentioned. In case the approach isn't valid / reliable, I'd like to know why.

Comment: Umm.. The accepted answer mentions `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins`, and the question itself mentions `about:plugins`.

Comment: Yeah, my takeout is that, regardless of version, we should be using what's stated @ about:plugins (which was already known by OP, but - I believe - he wasn't sure if that path was the _de facto_ path to be used or not).

Comment: OK.. You should cite the source where you got this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For flash player, using Ubuntu 16.04 64bit, `/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/` is sufficient.

After downloading `flash_player_npapi_linux.x86_64.tar.gz` from Adobe website, I unpacked the archive and :

```
$ sudo cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/
$ sudo cp -r usr/* /usr
```

Restarted Firefox and done!

I can even see that `/etc/alternatives/mozilla-flashplugin` is a link to `/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so`

Comment: because the page about:plugins gave me the path /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin for the shockwave flash plugin